# Drip feed array data with RxJS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, rxjs, jestjs

I am trying to drip feed array data, so it acts like it's coming in one at the time with RxJS.

What i want to achieve is i have a promise that gives an array like this:
`['a', 'b', 'c']`
Then i want to emit one value at the time like this:
`['a']`
`['a', 'b']`
`['a', 'b', 'c']`
So i can use it in a backtest. I did it like this, but i don't know if it can be done in a cleaner way?

```
const createDripDataObservable = OHLCData => (
  Observable.range(1, OHLCData.length)
    .map(t => OHLCData.slice(0, t))
)

export const dripObservable = (promise, ObservableFunc = Observable.fromPromise) =>
  ObservableFunc(promise)
    .flatMap(data => createDripDataObservable(data.data.result[TIME_FRAME]))
```

The reason for adding `observableFunc` is because apparently marble test in RxJS 5 doesn't accept promises. This is the most clean way i could think of. But maybe there is another way? I would like to just add a promise, so the test is more realistic.

```
describe('Historic market data', () => {
  it('should drip historic data so it acts like real time', () => {
    const testScheduler = new TestScheduler((a, b) => expect(a).toEqual(b))
    // setup
    const lhsMarble = 'x'
    const expected = '(abc)'

    const lhsInput = { x: { data: { result: { [TIME_FRAME]: ['a', 'b', 'c'] } } } }
    const expectedMap = {
      a: ['a'],
      b: ['a', 'b'],
      c: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    }

    const lhs$ = testScheduler.createHotObservable(lhsMarble, lhsInput)

    const actual$ = dripObservable(lhs$, Observable.from)

    testScheduler.expectObservable(actual$).toBe(expected, expectedMap)
    testScheduler.flush()
  })
})
```

I'm pretty satisifed with the test, except that i can't add a promise so i have to do `Observable.from`

I'm fairly new to RxJS and reactive streams so i would like some feedback on this!

Comment: You have working code that you ask to be reviewed. Sounds like this is off-topic on SO and rather belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: `createHotObservable` returns an Observable so where you have a `Promise` in your code?